# WebRTC and unwanted download of a file

Tags: webrtc

Theortical question here.. Is it possible that WebRTC would be misused to push files to everyone browsing the site?
Here's a scenario:
A malicious player shares a malicious file via a WebRTC platform and once someone has browsed that platform that file would be pushed into his system and preform its malicious act.
I know that when trying to access the webcam, WebRTC asks for the users permission, is it the same with file sharing?

Comment: Unless you're asking how to do this, this isn't a programming question. And if you are, you haven't included what you've tried. If you're visiting a malicious server, it seems irrelevant whether its malicious payload comes directly from its server(s) or someplace else. Its problem is going to be the same: how to get it executed outside the browsers' JS sandbox, so there's only permission prompts on exposing cameras and microphones to JS, not on (peer-to-peer) communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have APIs that execute a file on the users system, for a number of good reasons.

WebRTC doesn't add such an API (and in itself, does not have a filesharing API).